# ReactJS: Go to anchor link in HTML with react router dom only after the full page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've got a React app with URLs defined with React Router:

```
const App: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/rules" />
        <Route
          exact
          path={["/rules", "/rules/:placeId"]}
          component={LandingPage}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={["/route", "/route/:start/:end"]}
          component={RoutePage}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I want to allow the user to go to a specific accordion of the document if the url contains a hash part like this `/rules/someplace#accordion-3`

I have a component that returns the accordions in question, which all have an id:

```
const CategoryDisplay: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
...
  return (
    <>
      <Accordion
        id={`category-${accordion.id}`}/>
    </>
  );
};

export default CategoryDisplay;
```

And when I open an URL with an anchor like `/rules/someplace#accordion-3` while I'm already on the page, everything works fine and it scrolls to the element. However, on the initial load of the page, this behavior doesn't work.

How would I go about scrolling to the element only after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the idea would be to use an [effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to scroll to the appropriate component after the component mounts. Perhaps something like this:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    const anchor = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    if (anchor) {
        const anchorEl = document.getElementById(anchor);
        if (anchorEl) {
            anchorEl.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
}, []);
```

Notes:

- I haven't tested this.
- useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect may give a better experience here; see [this article](https://reacttraining.com/blog/useEffect-is-not-the-new-componentDidMount/) for details.
- I'm bypassing React and using the DOM. I usually try to avoid that, but since this logic is isolated and inherently focused on browser DOM behavior, I think this is a good use case for it (instead of complicating the code by pulling in more interactions with your React components.)
- scrollIntoView is convenient but [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#browser_compatibility); consider using the [scroll-into-view-if-needed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view-if-needed) NPM package instead.

Comment: Worked great after I changed the function to get the anchor to `const anchor = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];`
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I updated my code to get the anchor correctly. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly.

I think, you should make a function for wait everything complete.

but, if you can't catch exactly timing when everything fine,
you can use trick.

example :

```js
    const CategoryDisplay: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
        ...
        const [accordionId, setAccordionId] = useState("");
        useEffect(()=>{
          // this component mounted
          ...
          setTimeout(()=>{
            // do something
            setAccordionId(`category-${accordion.id}`);
          },0);
        }, []);
        return (
          <>
            <Accordion
              id={accordionId}/>
          </>
        );
    };
```

This will definitely run in the frame after the component mounted.